# Module installation using drush giving error

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drush

I have downloaded drush and cofigured it properly .Now I am trying to download a module "themekey" and install it to my drupal .Its downloading properly using

```
drush dl themekey
```

but when I try to install it using

```
drush en -y themekey
```

I get this error

```
drush en -y themekey
Command pm-enable needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will   [error]
need to invoke drush from a more functional Drupal environment to run
this command.
The drush command 'en themekey' could not be executed.               [error]
A Drupal installation directory could not be found
```

Please help me in this , I am new in drpal drush and did not find way to solve this 
Here is my drupal folder

```
 /opt/lampp/htdocs/projects/drupal_test/
```

Comment: @TheodorosPloumis I tried to change localhost to 127.0.0.1 .Other than this I didn't find anything sort out my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a working drupal installation, meaning php can be executed the mysql server can be reached. Then you have to change into the root directory of your installation - in your case:

`cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/projects/drupal_test/`

and execute the command:

`drush en modulename -y`

For debugging use

`drush rq`

Comment: drupal_test is my working drupal installation, I am working on that.Please clarify me that what do mean by "working drupal installation"

Answer (score 1):

If you tried changing localhost to 127.0.0.1 in settings and it still doesn't work, please have a look at the solution I found [here](http://log.itto.be/?p=1127):

```
Drush: “Command pm-enable needs a higher bootstrap level to run
```

When running drush you can run into this error message. In my case, the mysql command line tool provided with Mamp Pro was not available. You can easily test this by typing the command ‘mysql’ in terminal. Your output might be -bash: mysql: command not found.

To solve this, do the following in terminal:

```
sudo vim ~/.bash_profile
```

Press i
Move to the last line and append

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/:$PATH
```

Hit escape
Type in `:wq` (including the colon) to write the file and quit vim.
Reload your profile by running source `~/.bash_profile`.

The mysql command AND drush should now work!

Comment: hmm but it seems you are using mac Os but I am in linux and I m using Xamp. Hope the reason you provide is perfect but I need solution for xamp for linux

Comment: Are you sure you're executing the drush command at the root of your project?

Comment: I have figured out I tthink the command i am writing was not proper "drush en -y modulename " but when I tried drush en modulename -y it worked.

Comment: Oh... that's what @jojomojo said just above me... I thought you had tried his solution before I wrote mine... Sorry then :-)